# Convert variable value from two variables into a separate variable value

Tags: stata, data-management

I have the following data matrix containing Poole dw-nominate scores:

```
con  statenm    party   name     dwnom1
 80    USA       100    TRUMAN   -.276
 80   ALABAMA    100    BOYKIN F -.026
```

I was wondering if there was a way in Stata to turn the USA dwnom1 value into a specific variable, USA_dwnom1. I'd like to have each variable with a value of cong == 80 to have the value of -.276 for each value of the new variable of USA_dwnom1.

Once more, I was wondering if there was a way to do this in a loop (I'm doing this from the 80th to the 112th Congress).

Comment: You got a good answer, but you seem to be aiming at the intersection of (a) experienced Stata users (b) people familiar with details of US politics (c) people who know the kind of data you are dealing with. Explaining details known by (b) and (c) would increase your readership to (a). Also, this ended up on SO, where many people expect an attempt at code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. Here's one using a user-written command `xfill`:

```
clear

input con  str7 statenm party   str8 name dwnom1
80   USA         100    "TRUMAN"     -.276
80   ALABAMA     100    "BOYKIN F" -.026
end

net from http://www.sealedenvelope.com/
net install xfill

gen USA_dwnom1 = dwnom1 if statenm =="USA"
xfill USA_dwnom1, i(con)
```

`carryforward` is another option. Some other first-principles solutions that use `replace` and subscripting can be found [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/).

There's no need to loop over congresses.